# Is there any way to detect phone calls in windows phone 7 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listener, windows-phone

I am an android developer new to windows phone development. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) is the android equivalent of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't detect calls.  Additionally, assuming you are considering an app that will run in the background and listen for calls, then do something, in Windows Phone, apps don't "run" in the background.  When you start another app, go back to the start screen, or turn off the phone, the app will be either be deactivated, or tombstoned, depending on whether something else was loaded up that bumped it out of the memory or not.

Here is a link to learn about the application life cycle: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Application_Life_Cycle_-_Windows_Phone_7_Mango

You **can** have background tasks, but those only run occasionally, and without having a set schedule.  The phone runs background tasks at times that it can most efficiently use the radios in the phone, since starting up the radios is a rather intensive task.  Generally, don't expect tasks to have any predictable running pattern more accurate than about every hour.  It can be more frequent, but I wouldn't count on it, or you're setting yourself up for problems.

Here is a link regarding background tasks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=vs.92)

Answer (score 0):

No, the current Windows Phone 7.x SDK's don't allow you to detect calls.